# How to calculate the time span in Tcl using clock commands

Tags: tcl

I need to calculate the time difference between two periods of a day in a 24:00 hr format clock using Tcl.

Let's say my start time is 06:30:00 in the morning and end time is 18:30:00 in the evening. I've tried the following in using Active Tcl 8.5 and 8.6 in windows.

```
set morn [clock scan 06:30:00 -format %H:%M:%S]
set even [clock scan 18:30:00 -format %H:%M:%S]
set diff [clock format [expr $even - $morn ] -format %H:%M:%S]
```

The answer is supposed to be 12:00:00 which is the actual difference but, I get the answer as 17:30:00 which is totally confusing.

I presume that the GMT time difference of 05:30:00 is being added to the difference as I'm in a GMT+5:30 time zone (IST).

How do I get the exact difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clock` command doesn't have anything in it to convert time *intervals* into human-readable form, as it focuses on handling time *instants*.

You're correct that the timezone you're in caused that time interval to come out strange. Passing the `-gmt 1` option would have helped a bit, but only until you got a time interval of 24 hours or more. At that point, it would have looped round and looked very strange.

The way to deal with this is to do the formatting directly. This isn't very hard.

```
proc formatTimeInterval {intervalSeconds} {
    # *Assume* that the interval is positive
    set s [expr {$intervalSeconds % 60}]
    set i [expr {$intervalSeconds / 60}]
    set m [expr {$i % 60}]
    set i [expr {$i / 60}]
    set h [expr {$i % 24}]
    set d [expr {$i / 24}]
    return [format "%+d:%02d:%02d:%02d" $d $h $m $s]
}
```

```
puts [formatTimeInterval [expr {$even - $morn}]]
#==> +0:12:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much... that helped a lot :-)

Comment: I should mention that these are *ideal* days, not real ones, and so do not take into account complexities like DST changes, etc. Interval handling (like everything to do with time) is harder than it appears at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't use the -timezone option ?
I'm in TZ=CET so for me the answer is 13:00:00

If I add the "-timezone UTC" option I get the right answer:

```
set morn [clock scan 06:30:00 -format %T]
puts "morn = $morn"

set even [clock scan 18:30:00 -format %T]
puts "even = $even"

set diff [clock format [expr $even - $morn ] -format "%Y:%m:%d %T"]
puts "diff = $diff"

puts "difference = [expr $even - $morn]"

puts "with -timezone UTC = [clock format [expr $even - $morn ] -timezone UTC -format %T]"
```

The display is

```
morn = 1496723400
even = 1496766600
diff = 1970:01:01 13:00:00
difference = 43200
with -timezone UTC = 12:00:00
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for the suggestion. Apparently "-timezone UTC" did work just like "-gmt 1" as quoted by Donal.

Comment: "GMT +1" or "UTC +2 for me as my TZ is CEST. And for you ?

Comment: I set up my UNIX machine (sorry, I don't have opportunity to set up on a Windows machine) and see the result:
$ sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
Time Zone: Asia/Kolkata
.
Result of the same commands as above:
morn = 1496710800
even = 1496754000
diff = 1970:01:01 17:30:00
difference = 43200
with -timezone UTC = 12:00:00